# ssh does not use ssh-agent on FreeBSD

Tags: ssh, freebsd, openssh

I recently set up a new FreeBSD system and am having a lot of trouble getting `ssh` to use `ssh-agent`. I have verified with `ssh-add -l` that my key is added, and the `SSH_AGENT_PID` and `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` env vars are correctly set. The socket file clearly exists and has the right permissions too (`srw-------`).

However, running `ssh -vv` reveals that the agent is not even being picked up, hence my getting asked for the key passphrase each time.

Any idea what's going on here? Why isn't `ssh` picking up the running instance of `ssh-agent`, even though `ssh-add` clearly is, and everything seems correctly set?

```
FreeBSD 13.1
OpenSSH 8.8p1
OpenSSL 1.1.1o-freebsd
```

Comment: @Nasir Riley Thanks for fixing the formatting.